# Command line command to open http sessions to a service

Tags: http, session

I want to know if it is possible to open http sessions to a service through command line or batch file. 
What i want to achieve is check if a particular service is allowing more than x active connections .

Note: I cannot install any utility on my production machine.

Regards,
Prayag

Comment: Assuming you're running Linux, you can use the `wget` tool

Comment: Hi David,Thanks for your response. But sadly i am not on linux, i am on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... you can try to write a VBS file connecting to your webserver by telnet and requesting the root page.

Create a `.vbs` file and put this content. Then execute it from the prompt.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet www.yahoo.com 80~" 'subst www.yahoo.com with your host
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys "GET / HTTP/1.0~~"
WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "^C~" 'close telnet
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "exit~" 'close prompt
```